# How do you backup TFS on line?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I wanted to understand how others are backing up their TFS server on line?  I don't really want to use TFS on line from Microsoft as I have my reasons, however I wouldn't mind having their cloud as a backup somehow.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to 1) Use VSTS as a backup for an on-premise TFS installation? or 2) Create a local backup of a VSTS instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible.

VSTS uses standard SQL Azure and Azure Storage redundancy and disaster recovery techniques. Microsoft also take snapshots under the covers.

(I would  recommend that you use VSTS as it is far more secure and resilient than anything that you could run locally)

TFS stores all of  it's data in SQL and you use a marked transaction log system to back it up. The out-of-the-box tool for backups is your best bet. This creates a folder with your backups and will also do a restore for you.

You could  the sync that directory with Azure Blob Storage to store your backup online...